# else statement is resulting in identifier expected in c 13

Tags: c

I am a beginner at C and still learning the language

I can't tell what the error is about.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main (void)
{
    float hours,rate;
    printf("Enter the number of hours worked in this week:\n");
    scanf("%f",&hours);
    printf("Enter the pay rate\n");
    scanf("%f",&rate);
    if ( hours > 40 );
        printf("more than 40");

    else{
        printf("less than 40");
    }
}
```

//c:13 identifier expected

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a misplaced semi colon here `if ( hours > 40 );` just remove the semi colon.  It's good practice to indent the code properly to help detect these kind of errors.

Comment: Also good to use de brackets {}

Comment: erm sorry what does indent mean? i am sorry if i am troubling you

Comment: and thank you the code runs :D

Comment: indent means format like @Mike just did

Comment: @cleblanc except that Mike indent is wrong because of the extra ';' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess he wants something like that:
And of course as mentioned before the problem is the misplaced semicolon after the `if` statement.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main (void)
{
    float hours,rate;
    printf("Enter the number of hours worked in this week:\n");
    scanf("%f",&hours);
    printf("Enter the pay rate\n");
    scanf("%f",&rate);
    if (hours > 40)
    {
        printf("more than 40");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("less than 40");
    }
}
```